# Google Play APK upload failure with uses-permission maxSdkVersion

Tags: android, google-play

We have an app with the following manifest settings:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
```

The GET_ACCOUNTS permission used to be required for Push Notifications, but no longer required since API 16 (at least that is our understanding), so we used the maxSdkVersion option for this.

We've uploaded apps with these settings for awhile, and as recently as May 2015, but today (7/23/2015) we're getting an error from Developer Console:

[image]

We do use Google Play Services, and I have a guess that some change with this is the culprit.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute was not added to the [`<uses-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) element until API 19.

This means that if you set `android:maxSdkVersion` to anything below 18 you aren't going to get the behavior you desire- the first version of Android that can interpret that value is 19.

Comment: Agreed, but we've had this manifest option for some time and have uploaded apps to Google Play ... so something has changed.  Are you suggesting that this might be a new validation that the Play Store is performing, since a value below 18 doesn't make sense?

Comment: That's entirely possible. I can't say for sure what changed since Google doesn't offer a changelog. You could try contacting support to get further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!, I'll be removing the permission entirely as I agree with @Markaraujo, but will accept your answer as the right solution for those who might actually need GET_ACCOUNTS.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html is wrong 
as one can register/receive GCM messages just fine without that permission even 
on devices before ICS. Feel free to test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I suspect you're right and this will lead to resolution for me.  However, I think @Tanis answer is technically the better one for me to approve as an answer, since I think that this is just a new VALIDATION that Google Play is performing.